# Concat multiple query param in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom` v 5.2.0. I want to add multiple query params in the URL and I'm not sure how to accomplish it.
My route looks like this:

```js
<Route path="/admin/users" component={UserList} />
```

I want to pass multiple query params like...

```
/admin/users?search=hello&page=1&user_role=admin
```

Currently I'm doing it manually like...

```js
<Link to="/admin/users?user_role=admin" />
```

However, with this manual thing I cannot concat multiple query params. Is there a way to concat the query params dynamically? Does `react-router-dom` has it's own way of doing such things?

Comment: Yes, thank you @SMAKSS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make use of [`query-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) package to `parse` queryParams into object which will allow you to edit them easily and then `stringify` them before you pass them to link.

```
import qs from 'query-string';

...
const queryParam = qs.parse(location.search);
const newQueryParam = {
   ...queryParam,
   user_role: 'admin',
   something_else: 'something',
}


...
<Link to={{ pathname: '/admin/users', search: qs.stringify(newQueryParam)}} />
```

Comment: This works too. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to have helped. I just feel its a little more convenient than URLSearchParams

Comment: Yes, I felt the same after using both the solutions. I've accepted your answer because of the convenience.

Answer (score 4):

The answer was on the link provided by SMAKSS. The trick was to `set` the `key value` pair to the `URLSearchParams`.

```js
  const addQuery = (key, value) => {
    let pathname = location.pathname;
    // returns path: '/app/books'
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    // returns the existing query string: '?type=fiction&author=fahid'
    searchParams.set(key, value);
    history.push({
      pathname: pathname,
      search: searchParams.toString()
    });
  };
```

... and then you can use like this...

```js
<button onClick={() => addQuery("page", 2)>Page 2</button>
```